# 名 versus 名前: Why is this seemingly redundant Jukugo used?

Tags: kanji

For example I came across a Jukugo like this:

> 名 (name) + 前 (before) = 名前 (name)

What is the point in having this Jukugo when you apparently can just use `名`. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: 名前 is more polite than 名 but I don't know the reason. 
お名前 is more polite than 名前.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [語源由来辞典](http://gogen-allguide.com/na/namae.html) etymology dictionary, the 前 part is believed to have been added as an honorary form, mostly since the Meiji era.

Answer (score 3):

名, I have seen the meaning being given as "reputation". I think this is a better meaning than "name". Then "名前" means "what goes ahead of the reputation". Also to reduce ambiguity, 名 can be used as a counter and for other words.