# 名 and 名前 - the difference

Tags: word-choice, words

My impression is that, in speech, 名前 is polite, and 名 is ruder - but in writing, 名 sounds more literary. Am I correct?

Comment: [This post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19085/7810) may answer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

名前 is just "name", and sometimes お名前 is used in polite conversation, but 名 would not be used in conversation.  In literature you might see it like 彼の名は～～ but it sounds good only in a story context, not conversation unless you intend to sound like you are narrating something in a joking manner.

In school, when we would go to the teacher's room, sometimes teachers would tell us to 名乗れ！ meaning "Say your name" if we didn't greet properly.  But I have never heard 名 being used for anything else.

Comment: 名乗る is its own verb; you sometimes hear 名前を名乗れ.

Comment: Along with story context, it appears it can be used to denote reputation and level of Fame too  "Name; Title; Fame; Reputation" from https://jisho.org/search/名

Comment: Why is the anime "your name" called 君{きみ}の名{な}, instead of 君の名前{なまえ}?

Answer (score 1):

As Haya8 said, [名前]{なまえ} means name in both written and speech.

Polite way (not used for oneself): お名前

Ex. お名前は何ですか。

Common way: 名前

Ex. 私の名前は一郎です。

名 itself isn't used in speech. However, in written terms:

1. It can be a counter for people. ~名
   Ex. 5[名]{めい} means 5 persons.
2. It can be a suffix of something. ~名
   Ex. [会社名]{かいしゃめい} means Company Name